# Associated workspace is currently in use

Tags: eclipse

Programattically, I am switching over to different version of eclipse in the same workspace location but unfortunately some times pop up dialog comes and says " Could not launch the product because the associated worksapce is currently in use by another Eclipse application".

Could you please help how to overcome this issue while switching over to different version of eclipse plaugin?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing. Only one instance of Eclipse can use a workspace at a time.

Comment: If my eclipse project configured with different version of eclipse then I relaunching the eclipse so that it will switch over to that particular version eclipse in the same workspace location

Comment: shoot down the first eclipse instance entirely before starting the next one. Only one Eclipse instance can use a workspace at the same time.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to shutdown the first instance of eclipse programatically? I tried using PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close() but it did not help